# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection, Error appears when try to delete a row from a DB

Tags: c#, database, gridview, delete-row

```
Connection();
int Menu_Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Delete from menu where menu_id  =" + Menu_Id, con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from menu", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

I want to delete a row in gridview but this error appears,

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

On line,

```
int Menu_Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```

Comment: Well what is `e.RowIndex`, and how big is `GridView1.DataKeys`? (Also, please format your post more carefully - and stop building SQL dynamically...)

Comment: It would be interesting to know where do you call this code. Probably e.RowIndex is not set

Comment: i call this code in                            protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {}

Comment: and e.RowIndex represents the row being updated.

Answer (score 0):

The number in `e.RowIndex` is either negative or larger than the number of items in your `GridView1.DataKeys` collection. Use a debugger to find out why.

Comment: During debugging for e.RowIndex it showing me, unable to evaluate a function

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete it from the grid view, why not just do Gridview.Row.Visible = false; ? Otherwise check your rowIndex to make sure it is being set correctly. If you're using Visual Studio, while debugging there is a window called watch, just type your variable in there and it will update as it changes.

Comment: For e.RowIndex its showing me unable to evaluate an expression

Comment: @user3933853 When you click F5 to run/debug, your visual studio should change format a bit and there should be a few extra tabs on the bottom/side of the IDE. [Here's the official page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) EDIT: You have to keep running through your program steps until the event is created

Comment: So that means its getting the first row in your gridview. Is it still throwing the error?